# Apache Jena: What is a RDF Dataset?

Tags: dataset, rdf, jena

I am new to Semantic Web and I have a very basic question about
the JENA RDF Dataset. I read it from the documentation that a dataset is
a collection of graphs (or Models in the Java API). If I view the graph
(the model) as a RDF Alternative to Relational DB's 'Table', can I view
the dataset as a 'Database' ?

If so, then with TDB I should be able to create multiple
datasets. However in the documentation it says 'Every dataset is
obtained via TDBFactory.createDataset(Location) within a JVM is the same
dataset.' (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/datasets.html).  I
also recall that the documentation said somewhere that the TDB does not
support multiple JVM now. Does that mean with TDB I can create ONLY ONE
dataset?

Answer (score 4):

This is Andy's answer to my question in the jena users mailing list. Thanks, Andy.

> Hi, Everyone
>
> I am new to Semantic Web and I have a very basic question about
>   the JENA RDF Dataset. I read it from the documentation that a dataset is
>   a collection of graphs (or Models in the Java API). If I view the graph
>   (the model) as a RDF Alternative to Relational DB's 'Table', can I view
>   the dataset as a 'Database' ?

yes - sort of.

> If so, then with TDB I should be able to create multiple
>   datasets. However in the documentation it says 'Every dataset is
>   obtained via TDBFactory.createDataset(Location) within a JVM is the same
>   dataset.' (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/datasets.html).

... for the same "location" argument ...

TDBFactory.createDataset("DB1") ;
TDBFactory.createDataset("DB2") ;

are different datasets

> I
>   also recall that the documentation said somewhere that the TDB does not
>   support multiple JVM now. Does that mean with TDB I can create ONLY ONE
>   dataset?

TDB is the core database engine, and when used directly, you are using 
in a kind of embedded mode.

You can use Jena Fuseki for sharing a dataset between applications (just 
like you might share an SQL database between apps, except it's HTTP not 
JDBC).

Andy